# How recursively defined lazy val(with type Stream[T]) is evaluated in Scala

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I am confused about how lazy val is evaluated in Scala.

```
private def incrementStream: Stream[Int] = {
    def increment1(x: Int): Int = {
        println("increment: " + x + ", " + (x + 1))
        x + 1
    }

    lazy val n: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: (n map increment1)
    n
}
```

The above code recursively defines n.

When evaluating the first three elements of n, I think the evaluation trace would be as follows.

> n0 = 1

> n1 = 1 #:: (n0 map increment1) = 1 #:: 2

> n2 = 1 #:: (n1 map increment1) = 1 #:: ((1 #:: 2) map increment1) = 1 #:: 2 #:: 3

ni(n0, n1, ...) denotes the result after calculating i steps recursively.

In the above trace, incrementing 1 to 2 happens twice. Once in calculating n1 and once in calculating n2.

```
object Main extends App {
  private def incrementStream: Stream[Int] = {
    def increment1(x: Int): Int = {
      println("increment: " + x + ", " + (x + 1))
      x + 1
    }

    lazy val n: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: (n map increment1)
    n
  }

  println(incrementStream.take(3).toList)
}
```

However, when I executed the above code, I got the following result.

> increment: 1, 2

> increment: 2, 3

> List(1, 2, 3)

Incrementing 1 to 2 just happened once!

I don't understand how this is possible.
How is recursively defined lazy val evaluated?

Answer (score 2):

`Stream`s (which are deprecated since Scala 2.13 and have been replaced by `LazyList`s, for which the following applies as well) *memoize* the results, meaning that once an item has been computed it's stored in memory for it to be retrieved on a successive call.

I'm not familiar with the implementation details but in abstract you can think of a `Stream` as having a pass-through cache where items will be looked up before being computed (and cached).

This is relevant to keep in consideration in cases where this form of lazy memoization would lead to unwanted memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how this is possible. How is recursively defined lazy val evaluated?

In scala you have [parameters by name](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html)

> `By-name` parameters are **evaluated every time they are used**. They **won’t be evaluated at all if they are unused**. This is similar to replacing the by-name parameters with the passed expressions. They are in contrast to `by-value` parameters. To make a parameter called by-name, simply prepend `=>` to its type.

If you have a function that take a by value parameter, the value passed must be solved first

```scala
def paramByValue(i: Int) = i

paramByValue({
  println("by name must be computed")
  1
})
```

If you have a function that take a by name parameter (it's just receiving a function as parameter also known as higher order function), what is inside the function will never be executed if it is not invoked

```scala
def paramByName(f: () => Int) = 
  if(1 != 1) {
    f() // this line is not being called, meaning what is passed will not be computed
  } else 0

paramByName(() => {
  println("won't be printed") // the message will not be printed because the function is not being invoked
  1
})
```

That being said, the elements of [LazyList](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.12/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html) will not be evaluated until they are called.

If you check [LazyList.cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => LazyList[A]): LazyList[A]](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1a6c8c04217d8d5b8be787e7a776e11eb5a2a19a/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.scala#L1127-L1131), you would see the following code

```scala
    /** A lazy list consisting of a given first element and remaining elements
      *  @param hd   The first element of the result lazy list
      *  @param tl   The remaining elements of the result lazy list
      */
    def apply[A](hd: => A, tl: => LazyList[A]): LazyList[A] = newLL(sCons(hd, newLL(tl.state)))
```

As you can observe, it receives two params by name. First the `head` and then the `tail`. Because of that, `LazyList` can be infinite because the tail will not be loaded in memory until the elements are consumed.

If I define the following `LazyList`

```scala
val lazyList = LazyList.cons(
  { () =>
    println("the head")
    1
  }, {
    println("the tail")
    LazyList(2, 3, 4)
  }
)
```

and then do the following

```scala
lazyList.head // print `the head`
lazyList.tail // doesn't print anything
lazyList.tail.head // print `the tail`
```

as @[stefanobaghino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3314107/stefanobaghino) said, LazyList memoize the elements once they are consumed. It is detailed in the [scaladoc of the LazyList](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.12/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html)

> This class implements an immutable linked list. We call it "lazy" because it computes its elements only when they are needed.
>
> Elements are memoized; that is, the value of each element is computed at most once.

This means that if you have a side effect per each element (such as print to stdout) you will see the effect executed at most once.

---

The following artciles can give you more details

- [Scala - collections concrete immutable collection classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html#lazylists)
- [By-Value and By-Name Parameters in Scala](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/parameters-by-value-by-name)
- [LazyList in Scala](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/lazylist)